# Submit button in webform does not post any params

Tags: python, forms, python-requests, urllib3

I am trying to automate the submit form of [PantherDB](http://pantherdb.org/). I have previously used python with requests to send the different parameters to the form. Usually the "submit" button in the forms also sends a Param during the Post. But in this website ([PantherDB](http://pantherdb.org/)) the "submit" button does not send any Param during the Post.

How can I tell python that it should "click" the submit button?

This is what I have in my code.

```
url = "http://www.pantherdb.org"
files = {"fileData" : open(inputFile, "r")}

response = requests.post(url,  files = files, data = myParams)
```

Comment: You can't. Just submit all the fields to the correct url (`/geneListAnalysis.do`), or use `selenium`

Comment: Thanks, you are right in that the url was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do a network analysis in the developer tool of your browser when you are pressing the button and copy the curl command of the POST package.

Then you surf to [curl.trillworks.com][1] and convert the curl command it into a Python POST request.

Inside of your python request you can modify the values.